# what does 事 mean in this sentence?

Tags: words

In this context:
https://streamable.com/famk1v

She said: 事は一刻を争うわ お願いね

What does 事 mean?

Answer (score 4):

She's saying, "the situation is quite dire".  事 here refers to the situation at hand.  And thus she says お願い.  In other words, "Please donate some of your blood."